# Laravel Facade getting properties

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to wrap the Stripe PHP library with a facade in Laravel. I'm aware that this already exists, but unfortunately it's using a deprecated Stripe API and is behaving unexpectedly.

So I created a `Facade` and a `ServiceProvider` and updated the configuration to reflect this.

This is working as expected. When I try to call a method on my `Stripe` facade/alias, it redirects to the `StripeClient`:

```
>>> Stripe::foo()
PHP Error:  Call to undefined method Stripe/StripeClient::foo() in ...
```

However, the Stripe api uses class constants, like so:

```php
$stripe = new StripeClient(...);
$stripe->products->all();
```

But when I try to fetch these properties from the Facade, rather than redirecting to the `StripeClient`, it instead tries to get a class constant of the `Stripe` facade itself.

```
>>> Stripe::products->all()
PHP Fatal error:  Class constant 'App/Facades/Stripe::products' not found ...
```

So how do I do this?

Comment: did you add alias to config / app.php?